# Draw large 16:9 transparent PNG in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I'd like to draw a large (1920x1080) partly-transparent PNG over the whole screen in AndEngine. Textures have to be power-of-2 sized, and probably a lot of phones won't have support for textures that large anyway. Is there a straightforward way to add an image of that size to the scene in AndEngine, or am I going to have to manually slice it up into 256x256 chunks and render a bunch of them as sprites?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried loading a 2048x2048 image as a background image using AndEngine GLES1 and an old Android 1.6 phone. It works quite nice. There is some performance penalty though, but that would be the same if you used many smaller textures.

Comment: Hey, this is a bit old I know, but do you know what would be the best texture size ? In my game I am using a lot of different 1024x1024 images, would it be faster if they would be 512x512 ?

Comment: I don't know. If I understand correctly, the less textures you use, the better, so if you're deciding between two 512x512 textures and one 1024x1024, I would choose the latter.